# Disable Mvc3 hyperlink

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to disable a button action link using jquery-1.5.1 but nothing seems to work. i have tried the following lines of code seperately.

```
$('#btnSave').fadeTo("fast", .5).removeAttr("href");
 $('#btnSave').bind('click', false)
```

My aim is to disable the button after clicking so that the user does not click it again while the page is being  posted to the server.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of `.bind`

```
$("#btnSave").one("click",function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 //your code
 location.href=$(this).attr("href");
 $(this).attr("href","");

});
```

Comment: I just noticed that after click, the page does not redirect to the href. My object is to cater for people with slow internet that might be tempted to click the button again and again whilst the page is posted.

Comment: that is because the `href` value has been removed

Comment: What i have don is use e.preventDefault(); only. If i do that, the button's click event is ignored once button when i click it again the event fire. im using a buttonactionlink-@3nigma

Comment: @CodeNoob sry i just have lost track of your question... may be i misunderstood your question in the first place

Comment: You are on point but this does nope really do what I want. What i want is to let a user click a link then be redirected to a page. but because of slow internet speeds, i want to disable the link.

Comment: okay and the problem you are now facing is that the page is not redirected?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) instead of `bind()`:

```
$('#btnSave').fadeTo("fast", .5).removeAttr("href");
$('#btnSave').unbind('click', false)
```

Comment: will unbind work the same way as preventDefault() for the default event e? Such as firing an event like click?

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the default action of a hyper link using JavaScript inside of an event selector object:

```
$('#btnSave').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
})
```